# three radio buttons with sub radio buttons need to hide or show the div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on jQuery hide or show function. I have three radio buttons and two sub radio button will be available initially if user select the first radio button and user select children first / second radio button one div will be shown  in the second scneario if user select second radio button / third radio button from the parent and sub radio button second div should come. I am not getting how to do the if condition

Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/3rzq1baL/)

Here is my HTML code

```
<input type="radio" value="one" checked name="number" />One
<input type="radio" value="two" name="number" />two
<input type="radio" value="three" name="number" />three
<br/>
<input type="radio" checked value="onea" name="numbers" />one A
<input type="radio" value="twoa" name="numbers" />two A
<br/>
<div class="first">First</div>
<div class="second">second</div>
<div class="third">third</div>
```

Here is my current jquery code

```
   $(".second,.third").hide();
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() === 'onea'  || 'twoa') {
        $(".first").show();
    }
});
```

for the first radio button was working perfectly as expected but not for second third radio button

this is what i want

for example there are two scenarios 1) by default the one radio button was and one A radio button was checked the first div will show  2) if the user select two radio button / three radio button  and sub one A / two A second div will show I am not getting the second scenarios

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a very, very good look at `$(".first").show();`

Comment: I am not getting kindly please explain @MXD

Comment: If($(this).val() === 'onea' || 'twoa') this can now be both onea or twoa. But in both scenario's you look for the class called first. and show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efpvw81p/1/)

```
                    <input type="radio" value="one" name="number" />One
        <input type="radio" value="two" name="number" />two
        <input type="radio" value="three" name="number" />three
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" checked value="onea" name="numbers" id="first" />one A
        <input type="radio" value="twoa" name="numbers" id="second"/>two A
        <br/>
        <div class="first divcont">First</div>
        <div class="second divcont">second</div>
        <div class="third divcont">third</div>

        $(".second,.third").hide();
        $('input[type="radio"]').on("change",function () {
            var FVal = $('input[name="number"]:checked').val();
            console.log(FVal);
            if(FVal!='one'){
                $(".divcont").hide();
                $(".second").show();
            }else{
                 $(".divcont").hide();
                $(".first").show();

            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks for your effort but if the user select the second radio button  or third radio button and if the user select any sub radio button i have to show only one div kindly please help me

Comment: for example if user select second / third radio button and first sub radio button the first div show and if the user select the second radio button and second sub radio button the same div should show

Comment: i didnt get you @Mahadevan

Comment: for example there are two scenarios 1) by default the one radio button and one A radio button was checked the first div will show  2) if the user select two radio button / three radio button  and sub one A / two A second div will show I am not getting the second scenarios

Comment: You need to check first radio button value like  var RadioVal = $('input[name="number"]:checked').val();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95021/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-vel).